# Не применяются стили градиента к тексту

Tags: html, css

Использую CSS Hat в Photoshop, обычно все стили из него копирую.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно вывести такой текст,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шрифт подключил, он отображается корректно, но вот его цвет и заливка - нет.

Получается примерно следующее:

```css
h1 {
  text-shadow: 4.1px 5.7px 6.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: rgba(21, 9, 92, 0.1);
  font-family: AA;
  font-size: 140px;
  line-height: 130px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>Гонка<br>воинов</h1>
```

Как добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы ни чего лишнего в html и в css нету ! Вот это самый кроссбраузерный вид текстового градиента

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" id="svg">

  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop class="stop stop--1" stop-color="crimson" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop class="stop stop--2" stop-color="gold" offset="49%"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <mask id="mask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white">
    </rect>
  </mask>

  <g mask="url(#mask)">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dy=".25em" text-anchor="middle" fill="url(#grad)">Text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотри в сторону svg, наверное.
Градиентную заливку шрифта еще в браузерах не сделали.

Comment: То есть вставлять текст картинкой?

Comment: @Александр, svg может быть не только картинкой, но и разметкой. А для вебкитов градиентный шрифт делается при помощи обрезки фона по контурам букв, но особого смысла в этом нет, т. к. остальные не поддерживают. Svg надёжнее.

Comment: А можете привести пример разметки с текстом svg?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать заливку тексту через SVG. В принципе, этот метод позволяет делать не только градиентный текст, но и заливку паттернами, картинками, чем угодно.

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
}

text {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  fill: url(#MyGradient);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text y="70%">Your gradient text.</text>
</svg>
```

---

Источник: [Накладывание масок на текст, Лия Веру](http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/).

Answer (score 1):

```css
#gradtext {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue, green);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

font-size: 100px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="gradtext">ГОНКА ВОЙНОВ</p>
```

Для краткого реализовывания градиента на текст с помощью CSS надо `-webkit-background-clip:text;` и `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`
Цвета для градиента указываются как обычно в linear-gradient.
P.S. Подходит так же для -webkit-radial-gradient()

Answer (score -1):

Полноценно и кроссбраузерно повторить стиль этого текста средствами CSS не получится.
В вашем случае лучше вставить этот текст `.png` изображением. 
Не тратьте время зря.