# Как реализовать текст двух цветов

Tags: css, svg

Появился в макете такой дизайн кнопки 404:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как  я не искал, но не нашёл реализации данного дизайна

Подскажите как такое можно сделать

Comment: До безобразия просто: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndXk6.png" />`

Comment: Нельзя, нужно именно с css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Не применяются стили градиента к тексту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599696/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: Таково требование

Comment: именно css вы это вряд ли сделаете. svg вам в помощь

Comment: Если можно выделить текст внутри svg изображения то этот вариант мне подходит, только я не знаю можно ли так делать

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #212121 0%, #212121 50%, #b71c1c 50.5%, #b71c1c 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  HELLO
</div>
```

Вариант с `clip-path`

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #212121;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "404";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 15%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  color: #b71c1c;
}
```

```html
<div>
  404
</div>
```

Comment: Почему меня постоянно проверяет на то, робот ли я? Кто знает? Жутко бесит

Comment: Самое то, что нужно. Благодарю

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex такое происходит когда публикуешь ответ без текста, только сниппет

Answer (score 7):

Вариант на SVG

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 100">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .txt{
        font-size: 100px;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <path d="M220,-2 220,80 0,100" fill="red" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <text class="txt" x="20" y="80" fill="#3c4852">404</text>
  <text class="txt" x="20" y="80" fill="#48689a" clip-path="url(#clip)">404</text>
</svg>
```